# How could Wataru Minakami have 12 sisters out of the box?

Tags: sister-princess

At Sister Princess anime how could Wataru Minakami have 12 sisters. I mean if we consider he is between 15-20 yrs old, how could have too many younger sisters?

Also even the sisters come from different moms how could unexpectedly love them and know they have a big brother?

Comment: Haven't searched a lot, but 'officially" (= by the author) there is no setting about the age and the like. So apparently he got them 'just' out of the box...